# Are there any downsides to upgrading Python on Snow Leopard?

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I want to use the newest version of Python on Snow Leopard using the installer package, but I've read some confusing articles about conflicts when upgrading. I plan on using PyDev in Eclipse, will there be any conflicts with Snow Leopard if I upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question explicitly: Are there any downsides to upgrading Python on SL? Only if you upgrade the system installation.  It can have strange repercussions on any system/CLI tools that use Python, and on any bundled applications (.app) that are utilizing [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/) runtime libraries.

I would not upgrade, tangle with, or otherwise modify the default installation of Python, if that's what you are asking.  You are much better off installing an upgraded version of Python in an alternate location using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

MacPorts installs everything into `/opt/local` (i.e. `/opt/local/bin/python`) by default. You can then also install `python_select` which does some jiggering to make sure that whichever version you choose will be preferred based on your `PATH`.

You might want to consider using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) coupled with [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) for managing this environment as well, unless you become accustomed to MacPorts.  Things to consider!

Comment: Also the version straight from python.org will install in /usr/local/bin

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with using the one straight from python.org, right?

Comment: No there is not, so long as you don't also mind manual installation of your modules, etc.  I always point people to MacPorts when something like this comes up because it is a package manager, akin to `apt-get` and the like and makes it very easy to manage upgrades and dependencies.

Comment: Just make sure your PATH is set to pick up the right version. And if you're running web apps that your web server has the right PATH. And if you're running python scripts under launchd... etc.